Insulation and A/C system selection in a metal shed
I've got a 20x30 metal shed that I'm trying to finish out as an ADU. I don't know enough about insulation and A/C to choose what to install. The construction will be as follows from exterior to interior:

Metal exterior wall
1.25 in deep hat channel
2.25 in tubular steel frame studs with 2 in EPS or Polyiso between steel frame studs
1x4 in plywood furring strips hung horizontally (perpendicular across steel frame)
1/2 in drywall

So I have a couple questions:

What insulation should I use? The EPS is cheaper and more readily available near me. But the R value is like 10.5. Polyiso is something I'd have to order, it's twice the price, and I hear it's less resistant to moisture. But the R value is over 13.

The building will have two rmain partitions, a 5x30 and 15x30 side. On the 5x30 side there will be a closet, bathroom, and bedroom. The 15x30 side is wide open. I want to use a 2 head ductless system, but idk if it can throw air uniformly over a 30 ft long room that's only 5 ft wide, especially with partitions to separate the rooms. The other option is a traditional AC system but that takes up room. I'm thinking maybe I can spread the air from room to room with wall vents?


This is all in central Florida btw
Any help is appreciated.


I'm not sure how you condition rooms without putting air into them.  I'm just curious what a 5 foot wide bedroom looks like.  I assume you understand your local codes and whether or not your plans will even be allowed.

Codes are no problem, I don't live close enough to anyone else for them to care. The bedroom is actually 7 x 7. It's less of a bedroom and more of a cubby you can close for a second when one person is awake and getting ready and the other person is still sleeping. Most of the time it will be open. But the rest of the smaller partition is 5ft x 23 ft long. With a 13 x 5 bathroom at the other end and 10 x 5 closet in between.

You have planned for windows, right? It's not a legal (or safe!) bedroom without an egress window.

Yeah that was my bad when I initially planned this thing. I'm installing a window on that side.
